# Is it possible for the dihedral angles of a polyhedron to all grow simultaneously?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

Suppose $P$ and $Q$ are combinatorially equivalent non-self-intersecting polyhedra in $\mathbb{R}^3$, with $f$ a map from edges of $P$ to edges of $Q$ under said combinatorial equivalence. Let $\theta(e)$ be the dihedral angle of edge $e$.

If it is the case that for all $e\in D$, $\theta(e)\le \theta(f(e))$, must we have $\theta(e)=\theta(f(e))$ for all $e$?

That is, is it possible to distort the geometry of $P$ such that no dihedral angle decreases, and at least one dihedral angle increases?

My intuition is that this should not be possible, that there is some conserved notion of "total curvature" which would be violated by such an operation. But I can't seem to prove any such invariant (the sum certainly isn't one, for instance).

I'm also interested in the restriction to the convex case, ie where every dihedral angle is less than $\pi$.

Comment: One approach to this problem that seems promising is to consider the spherical graph in which vertices are the normal vectors to faces, and edges are between any two adjacent faces. Then we're asking about a distortion of this graph in which every edge length increases. Frustratingly, there *do* exist graphs of polyhedra on the sphere which can be distorted so every edge length increases - it's just that the ones I've found so far aren't valid adjacency graphs after the distortion, because the faces have moved far enough apart that they don't share an edge on the resulting polyhedron anymore.

Comment: But it seems plausible to me that a careful accounting of when such graphs can correspond to real polyhedra might let one make progress in this framing.

Comment: Maybe ask this at MO?

Comment: [Asked!](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466174/is-it-possible-for-the-dihedral-angles-of-a-polyhedron-to-all-grow-simultaneousl)